# Can the Autocomplete delay be lowered in forms?

Tags: 7, forms, search, ajax

I have seen that the autocomplete widget in Forms API is started when I finish typing, or when there is a delay between one key hitting and the next one. Could it be configured so it is launched as soon as I press a key, like in Google Autosuggest or other search boxes?

Comment: That delay is the time it takes the AJAX request to come back from the server (plus maybe a nominal delay for UX)

Comment: I have to disagree with my esteemed colleague @Clive here, as the delay from the UX is not nominal and is built into the Drupal autocomplete functionality.

Comment: I knew there was one in there @MPD, didn't realise it was as large as 300ms. Can see why they did it

Comment: I think that the behaviour is intentional. Also there seems to be a higher delay when the user doesn't stop typing, which seems intentional. If he/she is typing with no pause, probably knows perfectly what she is searching and doesn't want to be bothered with suggestions. I find the speed now good, if I have this in mind. ITOH, the time lapse of 300ms reminds me of another timelapse in PhoneGap, which is similar, and is also built in into the system, with ways of circumventing it. It might be a matter of preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Clive suggested in a comment major part of the delay is because of the time taken by your server to populate the dropdown list. This generally happens because Drupal has to load all the enabled modules and do a complete Drupal bootstrapping.

In special cases like Autocomplete responses that may not be necessary. Hence you can load only what is required and do a minimal Bootstrapping.

You can check out the details of how this is done on [this page.](http://www.tech-wanderings.com/speeding-auto-completes)

`Note :` This involves custom coding and will not to perform any access checks unless you manually do it.

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed, to reduce almost x10 the time consumed. I was seeing all the data returned via AJAX and almost dismayed. Maybe with this approach it will be easier.

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, there is a delay with AJAX autocomplete due to the server round trip.  However, there is a delay baked into Drupal itself.

In misc/autocomplete.js, there is this section of code

```
Drupal.ACDB = function (uri) {
  this.uri = uri;
  this.delay = 300;
  this.cache = {};
};
```

The delay property is used in `Drupal.ACDB.prototype.search` to debounce the search requests when a user is typing, so that the input has to be stable for 300ms before triggering the autocomplete callback.

You can get around this by [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), and providing your own version of `Drupal.ACDB` that uses a different delay.

Comment: I edited that value, but didn't see any speed gain. Also I found this misleading: when I start typing, no indication of suggestions appear. Stop typing & suggestion appear, and from then, different keys offer different suggestions. Maybe what I called _delay_ is the normal behaviour?

Comment: @Cesar That is the way this is supposed to work.  The delay is from the last keystroke to the AJAX callback so you don't do wasted calls while the user is still typing.  It sounds like your problem is with the actual AJAX callback.

Comment: Well, in fact I didn't presume that it was a malfunction or something. In my question, last sentence, I only ask for another way of working which is found elsewhere on the net: `Could it be configured so it is launched as soon as I press a key, like in Google Autosuggest or other search boxes?`  I only wanted to know if this behaviour could be imitated. Another thing is the delay, and even the lots-of-data that the server sends back, which may slow down the process in certain cases, but seems to be necessary for security - and other - reasons.

Comment: @Cesar Sorry for the confusion.  Yes, this would be possible, but it would require a pretty big rewrite of the standard autocomplete system, as you would not have multiple simultaneous callbacks which you need to handle.    The best way to accomplish this is to clone autocomplete.hs, and then hook_js_alter() in your own version.  You are trading latency for additional system load (for processing requests that don't get used because the user is still typing).

Comment: @Cesar Also keep in mind a search against a single character can produce a huge result set in some instances.  It's all a balancing act.

Comment: Yes, you have made me change my mind. I will let the default behaviour, I think the functionality has been carefully designed. Sites like Google can offer such functionality, but for a normal site it is better to restrict it a little.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) Module.

Refer [How to use autocomplete deluxe programatically](https://www.drupal.org/node/1329448)

May be this will help you.

Comment: I used Autocomplete Deluxe for other part of the project (highlight suggestions) and didn't convince me. I opted to modify the PHP autosuggestion code to get the highlight myself.